# AWS Lambda - bash: lambda: command not found

Tags: lambda

I was working on the Lambda Tutorial through the AWS CLI after creating the IAM and role. However, I tried to execute the following function, but an error occurs.

**function command:**

```
$ lambda create-function
...
```

**error**

```
bash: lambda: command not found
```

I tried searching for errors, but I could not find any article about lambda command not found. What's wrong with me?

Comment: It's likely that you don't have python on your machine, or are running an old version that uses easy_install instead of pip.

Comment: I think you're missing 'aws'. the command is 'aws lambda create-function`

Comment: I have installed version 3.7 of python and use pip.

Comment: It was! John Thank you.